# 75:15: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory #include_next <stdlib.h>

Tags: c++, qt-creator, fedora, cgal

I'm a beginner in working with CGAL libraries , I tried to run a combinatorial map example qt-creator on fedora after combiling CGAL:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include <CGAL/Combinatorial_map.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

typedef CGAL::Combinatorial_map<3> CMap_3;
typedef CMap_3::Dart_const_handle Dart_const_handle;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    CMap_3 cm;
    // Create two tetrahedra.
    Dart_const_handle dh1 = cm.make_combinatorial_tetrahedron();
    Dart_const_handle dh2 = cm.make_combinatorial_tetrahedron();
    // Display the combinatorial map characteristics.
    cm.display_characteristics(std::cout);
    std::cout<<", valid="<<cm.is_valid()<<std::endl;
    unsigned int res = 0;
    // Iterate over all the darts of the first tetrahedron.
    // Note that CMap_3::Dart_of_orbit_range<1,2> in 3D is equivalent to
    // CMap_3::Dart_of_cell_range<3>.
    for (CMap_3::Dart_of_orbit_range<1,2>::const_iterator
         it(cm.darts_of_orbit<1,2>(dh1).begin()),
         itend(cm.darts_of_orbit<1,2>(dh1).end()); it!=itend; ++it)
      ++res;
    std::cout<<"Number of darts of the first tetrahedron: "<<res<<std::endl;
    res = 0;
    // Iterate over all the darts of the facet containing dh2.
    for (CMap_3::Dart_of_orbit_range<1>::const_iterator
         it(cm.darts_of_orbit<1>(dh2).begin()),
         itend(cm.darts_of_orbit<1>(dh2).end()); it!=itend; ++it)
      ++res;
    std::cout<<"Number of darts of the facet containing dh2: "<<res<<std::endl;

    return a.exec();
}
```

**.pro file:**

```
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include
LIBS += -lgmp -lmpfr -lCGAL
```

but it shows the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:59:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/algorithm:62,
                 from /usr/include/QtCore/qglobal.h:68,
                 from /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qcoreapplication.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/QCoreApplication:1,
                 from ../untitled/main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/cstdlib:75:15: fatal error: stdlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include_next <stdlib.h>
```

I searched about the problem , but nothing is working with me
I appreciate any help 
thanks

Comment: Does the file `/usr/include/stdlib.h` exist?

Comment: yes,it's exists

Answer (score 11):

I solved it by removing INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include from .pro file

Comment: I have a somewhat similar issue, related to qt and G++; it is being said that it somewhat has to do with -isystem or -I, but unfortunately I don't have yet found a simple explanation, and how to resolve this. C++ is just too complex for its own good, since this include_next must come from some pre-compiled headers which then breaks (even more so if you use non-standard paths, which I do, so this ties me down in regarsd to flexibility).

Answer (score 0):

I got an solution: replace all #include_next with #include.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).